# Query working in phpmyadmin but not in php script page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been racking my brains for this all afternoon. Ive search various forums and web sites and nothing seems to be working right.

This is the SQL query that i got help with earlier from a member on Stackoverflow and works perfectly in phpmyadmin SQL query window

```
UPDATE members SET  `status` = IF( (
SELECT monday_ashore
FROM system
WHERE id =  '1'
) =  'Yes',  'ASHORE',  `status` );
```

and this is the code that i have in the php script:

```
//Monday Force All Ashore Cron Page <?php
include ("../config/db_connect.php");
$sql = ("UPDATE members SET  `status` = IF( (
SELECT monday_ashore
FROM system
WHERE id =  '1'
) =  'Yes',  'ASHORE',  `status` ");
?>
```

This script is set to be a CRON script. how do i get it to run by navigating to it through web site for testing and for it to actually work. What am i doing wrong or missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: usually when something works in one spot but not the other, it means there stands to be (an) error(s) somewhere.

Comment: There u go `$sql = "UPDATE members SET  status = IF( ( SELECT monday_ashore FROM system WHERE id =  '1' ) =  'Yes',  'ASHORE',  status )";`

Comment: Sorry your answer does not work in .php page

Comment: @MarkRhodes put on top of your script after `<?php` tags `error_reporting(1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` this will give you a real error.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see it's in your 'include' statement.  Since you are referencing it dynmaically with a '../' there is no guarantee cron will accept that (cron assumes you are starting from your home directory).  change that to a fully qualified directory name and that should solve your problem, as mentioned above fix your missing ')'

Comment: Tried doing what you have suggested, and it does not execute in the .php page. I changes the include line to the full web address and directory name, but still not executing the sql query.

Comment: You can't use a 'full web line'.  It would be something like */var/html/www/myproject/config/db_connect.php* which is a fully qualified file.  Do you have shell access?  did you try php MYPROJECT.php and see what it returns?